# Changing ubuntu server's language to english

Tags: language-support

I just got myself a dedicated server that's running Ubuntu 13.10 64BIT and it is in French language (console.online.net). Is there any way to install an English language package ?

I'm a Linux newbie and the fact that its in French doesn't help

Sorry, the comments didn't work for me so I just edit here :

I get:

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet language-support-en
```

When I type `sudo apt-get install language-support-en`

Somehow it doesn't just work :(

Comment: If French is your native language you shouln't be afraid of trying Linux in that language. There is a strong community of French speaking Ubuntu users [1]. [1] http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/

Comment: People suggested you to install "language-pack-en" and not "language-support-en" as you wrote in your updated question.

Comment: @JoachimRohde my friend OP is right.

Answer (score 41):

First install all the English language packages:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-en-base manpages
```

Then remove the French language packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove language-pack-fr language-pack-fr-base manpages-fr
```

And that should be enough.

**Edit I**: some users note that you might need to update the `/etc/default/locale` file yourself, make sure the first line in that file reads something like:

> LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"

**Edit II**: some users do not seem happy with the suggestion for the English used in Europe (I am assuming the enquirer is French). Those wishing to use a different English locale can get a list of available English locales with this command:

> locale -a | grep en_

Comment: You also need to edit `/etc/default/locale` and log off.

Answer (score 21):

Just install language-pack or edit the `/etc/default/locale` **doesn't work** for my **Ubuntu 17.10**, the way below is working for me.

---

Regenerating the supported locale list: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, and choose `en_US.UTF-8`.

Change the current default locale: `sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Then it works, doesn't need reboot.

Run `locale` to check your current locale.

Answer (score 12):

You need to edit `/etc/default/locale` so it contains

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

or some other English locale of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

To install English language pack

```
 sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
```

If you get the same error again , first run      `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 2):

Simply run:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

It will start the setup for system-language

Comment: This is a duplicate of another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1004783/65926)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same *problem* ... with online.net :)
This is what I'v made...

Edited /etc/default/locale and ~/.pam_environment

```
nano /etc/default/locale
```

Replaced the french line/lines with

```
LANG="en_US"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
```

Now pam_environment

```
nano ~/.pam_environment
```

Replaced the french line/lines with

```
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_US
```

Answer (score 1):

This Packages should be installed:

> sudo apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-en-base manpages

Then edit `/etc/default/locale` and set

> sudo vim /etc/default/locale
>
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8