# How to change the default country in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php

I connect to my Ubuntu server with command line.

I have installed Apache and, with cURL (PHP) I've tried to connect to [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/) and get data from that website.

But some of the data have German titles because of my server (which is in Germany), and I want to load all titles in English language!

I should change my default country but I don't know how to do that in Ubuntu.

I've searched and found these codes :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

First install the English language packs.

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-en-base manpages
```

You then need to execute `nano /etc/default/locale` and replace the French lines with:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
```

You can then remove the German langauge pack as thus:

```
sudo apt-get remove language-pack-de language-pack-de-base manpages-de
```

Reboot and you should have English as the default.

[More info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380746/changing-ubuntu-servers-language-to-english).

Comment: You mean Germany ?

Comment: @HamedAp Yes, my silly mistake. Didn't double check the answer. Too excited to help. Fixed the answer.

Comment: i do 2 steps . 3rd step do not uninstall anything . because i dont have DE language in my system !!!

Comment: "DE" is Deutsch(relating to Germany, people, language, etc). IF you don't have DE then that means you never had it.

Comment: What does the command `locale` return?

Comment: `# locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8

LANGUAGE=en_US:en

LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"

LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: Can you load the page that you loaded again? It should be in English(provided that you have logged out and logged in again.

Comment: again Germany ! no diffrent !

Comment: Weird. Your locale file returns US, but you still get German data. What does `cat /etc/localtime` and `cat /etc/timezone` return?