# set system-language to english: apt showing messages in spanish

Tags: apt, locale, system-language

I installed ubuntu, using english as a language.

Then I added spanish, meant to be used by another user.

Now whenever I do something in apt the messages are in spanish

This is the content of my locale file:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_AR.UTF-8"
```

I also tried running

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-en-base manpages
```

and also

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

in which I chose en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 and es_AR.UTF-8 UTF-8 (I don't want to mess the configuration of the spanish speaking user)

As default language for the entire system I choose: en_US.UTF-8
Also tried with:

```
$ sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:es
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Abd then I tried adding `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to my bashrc, but nothing seems to work.

Related questions:

- [Changing ubuntu server's language to english](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380746/changing-ubuntu-servers-language-to-english)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105588/how-to-have-console-messages-in-english

Comment: When you say that "the messages are in Spanish", do you mean everything, or are you talking about the date/time formats? If the former, can you please edit your question and show us an output example?

Comment: What about `LANG=C sudo apt update`, `LANG=C sudo apt ugrade`, `LANG=C sudo apt full-upgrade`, etc?

Comment: @DKBose: Shouldn't be necessary when both `LC_MESSAGES` and `LANGUAGE` are correctly set to English. That's why I asked how much Spanish is actually shown.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson okay, my system is English so I don't have real experience with troubleshooting such issues.

Comment: @DKBose: I suddenly spotted the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the reason.

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:es
```

You must have set that manually; the UI would not allow you to. The thing is that the en_US translation files typically do not include translations, since the original strings are supposed to be American English. So gettext looks first for a translation in en_US, does not find any, and then go looking for a Spanish translation.

You should change it to:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
```